# I filled the wrong income tax form, what should I do?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, form-1040x

I am a non-resident alien in the US and I filled form 1040 by mistake, which is for US residents. I think I should fill 1040X and 1040NR by paper, but I am not sure if I should wait until the return is rejected or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to file an amended return with the IRS.  You can find details [here](http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/IRS-Procedures/Amended-Returns-&-Form-1040X/Amended-Returns-&-Form-1040X).  I believe you'd file the 1040X and the NR.  Attach the 1040NR to the 1040X.

More detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040x.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know, but I think that's the case only when you filled incorrectly the right form. I have never filed the NR, just the 1040, which wouldn't be appropriate for me.

Comment: It might be good to file the X form and the one you should have filed, writing amended on the NR form.

Comment: Actually, you are supposed to attach the 1040NR to the 1040X. See 1040X instructions (http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040x.pdf), page 4, under "Resident and nonresident aliens"

Comment: @user102008 I've updated my answer.